Transmigration novel where a girl enters a novel she was reading on the subway
It is a fantasy transmigration-themed novel where a girl was reading a book on the subway or something then gets transmigrated into the novel (maybe had the same name as the character).
It begins with her waking up in her room and some woman comes in threating to kill her if she doesn't give up pursuing some guy. So she pretends to love this other guy who is supposed to be super strong but is disliked.
As the story progresses, she gains the power to summon these plant-like monsters that, when they consume the demon-like creatures, can produce these magic-type stones.
I think, toward the end, it turns out the female lead's memory or something was tampered with (and maybe she was the character all along).
I vaguely remember something about a prophecy or something about the male lead supposedly destroying the world, but it turns out he saves it instead.
Some other scenes I remember are the female lead and the male lead are in some kind of underground city and they end up destroying it. Also, there was a scene where there's a wall and a bunch of demons are trying to destroy it and her family is tasked with protecting it, but someone betrays them and she has to save them.
If I remember other stuff, I will update.

FML? And does "ML" mean "male lead"? Please [edit] and clarify abbreviations used.

I took FML to mean female lead. The more typical shortened form is FL (or fl), but given the rest of this description, it seems like a safe bet that the OP shortened it to FML in this case. Also, there's a strong possibility that this is a Korean online novel that may have been adapted into a manhwa/webcomic.
